# How to decode received data b'\x89A\....'

Tags: python-3.x, decode

Have this data received over a REST post udp service.

```
b'\x89A\x01 \x10\x07\x08hT#\x18\x1f\x03y9\x04\xff\xff\x02\xb7\xe2\x00p\x01<<<<r\x17\xff>'
```

Trying to decode by utf, ascii and base64 but cannot find a result which makes sense.

Someone an idea how I could find out what the right decoder is?

Comment: Closest I can find that doesn't cause an error is "windows-1252". Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
data = b'\x89A\x01 \x10\x07\x08hT#\x18\x1f\x03y9\x04\xff\xff\x02\xb7\xe2\x00p\x01<<<<r\x17\xff>'
data1 = data.hex().encode('latin1').decode('cp1252')
print(data1)
89410120100708685423181f03793904ffff02b7e20070013c3c3c3c7217ff3e
```

Thank you @3ddavies